# Using Azure API without login (using roles)

Tags: azure, roles, azure-cli

I'm trying to list virtual machines in azure from inside another virtual machine in azure. I mean, what I want to do is list backend members from the frontent. BUT I don't want to use credentials in my front end and I want to use roles.

For example, in AWS you can assign roles (EC2::DescribeInstance) to instances and use this command:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running Name=tag:myapp-member,Values=myapp-backend
```

I can run that command without expose my credentials in any place.

If I run something like this on Azure

```sh
az vm list
```

It says I need to login first.

And I can't find how to assign roles to the instance.

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Comment: Any more update for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, you can use the VM Managed Identity to log in for the Azure CLI, this way will not store any credential in the VM. But first, you need to assign the roles to your VM. And to assign the roles, you can use the Azure CLI command [`az role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create) and the steps in [Assign a managed identity access to a resource using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-cli). Or just in the Azure Portal, you can follow the steps in [Assign a managed identity access to a resource by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-portal). The PowerShell command is also available.

When the role is created, you can use the Azure CLI command `az login --identity` to log in without credential.

**Note**: You need to install the Azure CLI in the VM first.

Comment: Slight nitpick, MSI is now an old abbreviation :) It's usually referred to as Managed Identity.